# JBoss Fuse OSGi envers not working

Tags: jboss, osgi, jbossfuse, hibernate-envers, blueprint-osgi

I want to use hibernate envers auditing for generating aud tables and deploy it to Jboss fuse OSGi Karaf container.
Added @Audited notation in entity class and hibernate-envers jar in my pom file.

Here is my pom.xml file,

```
<parent>
    <groupId>fuse-examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>fuse-spring-hibernate-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>


<artifactId>fuse-blueprint-hibernate</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>Business Service</name>

<properties>
    <camel-version>1.5.0</camel-version>
    <maven-bundle-plugin>2.4.0</maven-bundle-plugin>
    <javax.persistence>2.0.0</javax.persistence>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.persistence}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>business-service</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Meta-Persistence>META-INF/persistence.xml</Meta-Persistence>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.hibernate.envers,
                        javax.sql,
                        javax.persistence,
                        org.hibernate.proxy,
                        javassist.util.proxy,
                        org.slf4j
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Include-Resource>src/main/resources</Include-Resource>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If i removed org.hibernate.envers from pom.xml, the table got created but _aud tables not generated.
What settings i missed?
Anything settings missed in osgi container or pom.xml?
Or anything want to setup in blueprint xml?

Help me.

Comment: You mention you added the hibernate-envers library but make no mention of your problem when you do.  Obviously, if you don't include it as your post says, then the audit tables won't be created.  Can you explain whta problems you faced when it was part of your pom?

Comment: I'm using hibernate-envers 4.2.22.Final-redhat-1 version in my parent pom file.

Comment: My question is, How to use hibernate envers in my bundle and how to deploy this in osgi karaf container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some researched did about JBoss Fuse Karaf based OSGi container, I completed the task.
Actually we building the bundle for deploying it to OSGi container, we should set some settings. First of all we should tell what are the packages load by OSGi container and what are the packages by embedding into bundle.
Bundle manifest file will define this. That is the root settings for every bundle.
In hardcore frameworks or dependencies can embed within the bundle.
My mistake was i just declared org.hibernate.envers for using hibernate envers.

```
                 <Import-Package>
                    org.hibernate.envers,
                    javax.sql,
                    javax.persistence,
                    org.hibernate.proxy,
                    javassist.util.proxy,
                    org.slf4j
                </Import-Package>
```

Most of times classloading issues may occur, If this occurs resources may null.
The solution is we should import everything envers imports.

Here i pasted my manifest file, It is working fine.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1481971039345
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_112
Built-By: Smile
Bundle-Activator: com.fuse.hibernate.services.OsgiBundleActiva
 tor
Bundle-Blueprint: OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml
Bundle-ClassPath: .,hibernate-envers-4.2.22.Final-redhat-1.jar
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: FUSE-HIBERNATE
Bundle-SymbolicName: fuse-hibernate
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: <Exported Packages>
Export-Service: com.fuse.repository.CustomRepository
Import-Package: org.hibernate.annotations;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernat
 e.annotations.common.reflection;version="[4.0,5)",javax.persistence;ver
 sion="[2.0,3)",org.hibernate.proxy;version="[4.2,5)",javassist.util.pro
 xy;version="[3.18,4)",org.slf4j;version="[1.7,2)",javax.management,java
 x.naming,javax.persistence.metamodel;version="[2.0,3)",javax.transactio
 n;version="[1.1,2)",org.apache.commons.beanutils;version="[1.8,2)",org.
 apache.commons.lang3;version="[3.0,4)",org.apache.tools.ant,org.dom4j,o
 rg.dom4j.io,org.dom4j.tree,org.hibernate;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernat
 e.action.spi;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.cache;version="[4.2,5)",or
 g.hibernate.cfg;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.collection.spi;version=
 "[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.criterion;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.diale
 ct;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi;version="[4.2,5)",or
 g.hibernate.engine.loading.internal,org.hibernate.engine.spi;version="[
 4.2,5)",org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibe
 rnate.event.service.spi;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.event.spi;versi
 on="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.id;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.id.enhanc
 ed;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.integrator.spi;version="[4.2,5)",org
 .hibernate.internal,org.hibernate.internal.util;version="[4.2,5)",org.h
 ibernate.internal.util.collections,org.hibernate.internal.util.config,o
 rg.hibernate.internal.util.xml,org.hibernate.jdbc;version="[4.2,5)",org
 .hibernate.mapping;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.metamodel.source;ver
 sion="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.metamodel.spi;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibern
 ate.persister.collection;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.persister.enti
 ty;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.property;version="[4.2,5)",org.hiber
 nate.service;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi;v
 ersion="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal,org.hibern
 ate.service.jndi;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.service.spi;version="[
 4.2,5)",org.hibernate.sql;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl;
 version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.type;version="[4.2,5)",org.hibernate.us
 ertype;version="[4.2,5)",org.jboss.logging;version="[3.1,4)",org.joda.t
 ime;version="[2.9,3)",org.osgi.framework;version="[1.6,2)",org.osgi.ser
 vice.blueprint;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)",org.w3c.dom,javax.sql
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
```

We can use Include-Resource tag for including hibernate as a resource and make sure to add this in bundle class path. It should work.